# Negating Drow disadvantage?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, drow

Everyone says I'm crazy, but I love playing Drow. The only tiny, little, gigantic problem is the disadvantage on EVERYTHING in direct sunlight. So, is there any way to negate the disadvantage on a roll in sunlight, or should I just play lots of Underdark campaigns?

Comment: Sorry, it totally is. Taking it down now.

Comment: And... I can't figure out how.

Comment: under your question -> share edit close **delete** flag

Comment: We actually like duplicate questions; since they get linked together, when someone searches here or in Google it makes the “main” question easier to find if there are multiple versions all linked to  it. That's why we don't use deletion to handle duplicates, but instead mark them as duplicates and leave them on the site. So I've corrected that now by undeleting and linking this as a duplicate. Thanks for contributing to the searchability of RPG.se!